# How can I pipe the result of "find" to my bash script?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to pipe the result of a `find` command to a bash script. This is to simplify (maybe automate) a process I have been working on.

This is the command I would like to run

`find . -type f -iname '*.mp4' -exec echo {}|./indexer.sh \;`

`indexer.sh` is ofc `chmod +x` so it can execute.

`indexer.sh` currently contains

```
#!/bin/zsh
read foo
echo "You entered '$foo'"
```

And if I run `$ echo foo | ./indexer.sh` I get the output of
`You entered 'foo'`

But when I run `find . -type f -iname '*.mp4' -exec echo {}|./indexer.sh \;` I receive the following error message:

```
find: -exec: no terminating ";" or "+"
You entered ''
```

So how can I pipe the output of find, into my script?

Comment: Notice that you didn't escape `|` from the shell, so `find` doesn't see anything after the `{}`.  I don't think `find -exec` even uses a shell, though, so I wouldn't count on `|` or `>` working even if you did escape them.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I would rewrite it using a parameter instead of a read statement and piping,

```
find . -type f -iname '*.mp4' -exec ./indexer.sh {} \;
```

with the following indexer.sh,

```
#!/bin/zsh

echo "You entered '$1'"
```

Comment: Or better, use `printf 'You entered %s\n' "$@"` to expand a whole array of args, so you can use `find -exec ./indexer.sh {} +` instead of starting a new shell for every file found.

Answer (score 18):

Your misconception is that `echo {}|./indexer.sh` is treated as a unit.  It isn't.  What went wrong is that your shell interprets the pipeline *before* it runs `find`.  Therefore, it's running…

```
find . -type f -iname '*.mp4' -exec echo {}
```

… and piping the result to

```
./indexer.sh \;
```

As a result, `find` sees `{}` without the `\;` and fails.  (`indexer.sh` sees a superfluous `;` argument and ignores it.)

To fix your misconception, you would have to do…

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c 'echo "{}"|./indexer.sh' \;
```

… since that's the only way to treat that pipeline as a single command.

Of course, that's a monstrosity.  If you want to run `indexer.sh` once for each MP4 file, take [the advice from @sudodus](/a/1413483/165556) and avoid the pipe altogether.

Answer (score 7):

The `\;` needs to be positioned before the pipe. Since i don't have `zsh` and your question is tagged with `bash`, i'll use `bash` for an example.

**indexer.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

while read foo
do
    echo "You entered '$foo'"
done
```

**execution example**

```
$ find . -type f -iname '*.mp4' -exec echo {} \; |./indexer.sh
You entered './subdirectory/d.mp4'
You entered './subdirectory/c.mp4'
You entered './b.mp4'
You entered './a.mp4'
```

**optimization**

This use case of find could be optimized by removing the `.` directly after find and the whole `-exec` part at the end. The output of find would be the same without it.

```
$ find -type f -iname '*.mp4' |./indexer.sh
You entered './subdirectory/d.mp4'
You entered './subdirectory/c.mp4'
You entered './b.mp4'
You entered './a.mp4'
```

Comment: Why use `find ... -exec echo {} | ...` and not just `find ... | ...` (without `exec` and `echo`. On my system both produce the same result, is there something I am missing?

Comment: @user000001 i added a paragraph about optimization. I'll leave the original version as part of the answer, because it addresses the error message `find: -exec: no terminating ";" or "+"`, which is part of OP.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't or don't want to change `indexer.sh` for whatever reason, you can also be explicit about your iteration with

```
find . -type f -iname '*.mp4' | while read file; do echo $file | ./indexer.sh; done
```

I use this pattern a lot. You may need to set `IFS` if you have spaces in your filenames, but I think you'd have that problem with the other solutions as well.

Comment: sudodus's answer (passing the filename as an arg to the script) avoids IFS problems, even for filenames containing newline.  All the answers that suggest piping would want to do something like `(IFS=$'\n';  find | whatever)` to temporarily set IFS in a subshell.  You would still want to quote any expansions, like `echo "$file"`.  That will work for any characters except newline in filenames.  (Which doesn't typically happen normally, but copy-paste errors into file selector dialogs can happen.)

Comment: You won't have an issue with spaces/special characters in filenames if you put quotes around "$file" and your script does the same with its parameters.